# The number of ways in which 6 pencils can be distributed between two boys such that each boy gets at least one pencil is

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of ways in which 6 pencils can be distributed 
>   between two boys such that each boy gets at least one pencil is

I think it is 5, but the answer is 62. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Looks as if the pencils have different colours.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. The problem should have specified whether the pencils are distinguishable or not. Without that, there is ambiguity, and your interpretation (and answer) are perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is indeed $5$ if one considers the pencils to be indistinguishable.

But if each pencil is distinguishable (say, a different color) then there are $2^6 = 64$ ways to distribute the pencils, $2$ of which leave one boy with no pencils. Leaving a total of $64-2=62$ ways.

The logic behind $2^6$ is that each of the $6$ pencils has $2$ places it can go. So there are $6$ factors of $2$.

Comment: Nice solution Eric Thoma......

Answer (score 1):

in order to have atleast 1 pencil with each boy, give 1 pencil to each. Now remaining 4 can be distributed among two in 5 ways only so I think u r correct.(pencils are same)